# Secondary thread inside other thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, web-services

This is my requirement. A web service need to be called on secondary thread to send persons data as array of dictionaries.
({name:person1,
  address:india
  photo:a path1
  };
  {name:person2,
  address:india
  photo:a path2
  } 
) 
In this for photo we have other web service, to which we upload image and get a path in response.

What I did.
Wrote a function and called it on secondary thread and started a activity indicator.
Inside function a for loop is making this dictionaries. It works fine.
But when I upload image inside this synchronously, activity indicator stops. If I do it asynchronously, by the time I get path response my main for loop is gone and I dont have the dictionary object to add the path.

```
 -(BOOL)callSynchWebService
 {
 __block BOOL validateFlag=NO;
 MBProgressHUD * progressHud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];

InterNetConnectionService *netService=[[InterNetConnectionService alloc]init];
if(![netService checkFornetConnectionWithStatus] )
{
    [self.view addSubview:progressHud];
    progressHud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    progressHud.labelText = @"Loading";
    [progressHud show:YES];
    for (Person *p in array_persons)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dict setObject:p.name forKey:@"Name"];
            [dict setObject:p.address forKey:@"Address"];
            NSString *photoResult=[self sendingPhototoServer:p.image];
            [dict setObject:photoResult forKey:@"Photo"];
    }
  }
```

Then used ASIHTTP to send this array.

Please can you help me to upload that image in this for loop asynchronously and store  its response in dictionary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my thought of how to solve your problem in nested network request. All network requests are asynchronous.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"example"];
NSArray *originalArray = @[@{@"name": @"person1", @"image": image, @"address": @"india"},
                           @{@"name": @"person1", @"image": image, @"address": @"india"},
                           @{@"name": @"person1", @"image": image, @"address": @"india"}];
__block NSMutableArray *uploadArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *item in originalArray) {
    //use AFNetworking here
    //all network request in AFNetworking is asynchronous
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager POST:@"example.com/imageupload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(item[@"image"]);
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"pic" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        [uploadArray addObject:@{@"name": @"person1",
                                 @"imagePath":responseObject[@"url"],
                                 @"address":@"india"}];
        if (uploadArray.count == originalArray.count) {
            [manager POST:@"example.com/arrayupload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                // convert the uploadArray to json or other and add to http body
            } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                //finished
            } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                //upload failed
            }];
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        //upload failed
    }];
}
```

If you need block the main thread during network request add the HUD.

Hope this can enlighten you on this question